# How to change volume mount

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, storage, mount

I have two volumes in my EC2 ubuntu instance:

```
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvdb  202:16   0    40G  0 disk /mnt
xvda1 202:1    0   400G  0 disk /
```

I want the 400GB one to be the main one that the server uses. However, this is currently not the case:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       32G  3.5G   27G  12% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            3.7G  8.0K  3.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs           752M  208K  752M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/xvdb        40G   49M   38G   1% /mnt
```

How would I mount the big `xvda1` volume as the main one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would I mount the big xvda1 volume as the main one?

Well, it looks like that's already the case. `/dev/xvda1` **is** mounted as your root filesystem (assuming that by "main one" you mean "root filesystem"):

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       32G  3.5G   27G  12% /
```

You may just need to expand the filesystem on that volume, something like this (assuming some sort of ext filesystem):

```
$ resize2fs /dev/xvda1
```

**WARNING**: before you do this, make sure you have a backup of all the data on that volume and some mechanism to easily and quickly recover it.